# How to get the data after "=" sign from a txt file?

Tags: java, string, file

I have a program, in Java, that will save data to a .txt file and save it like:

> intdata=2
>
> stringdata=hello

How will I read the data from the text file and specify the value I need. Lets say I want the intdata value, it would return the part after the equals.  How do I only return the part after the equals?

Comment: Use the `split` function for `String`s

Comment: @RyanJ can you provide a example?

Comment: There are many ways you could approach this, but the simplest would probably be to do all the saving and loading of this sort of data using the `java.util.Properties` class rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: @IanRoberts true, but I need to have multiple files in the program

Comment: That's fine, you can use a separate instance of `Properties` to manage each file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the key it's attached to:  use `String.split`.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
String value = scan.nextLine().split("=")[1];
```

If you *do* care about the key it's attached to:  use `String.split` in conjunction with a `Map`.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] line = scan.nextLine().split("=");
    values.put(line[0], line[1]);
}
```

Alternatively, if it's a proper `.properties` file, you could elect to use [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) instead:

```
Properties propertiesFile = new Properties();
propertiesFile.load(new FileInputStream("file.txt"));

// use it like a regular Properties object now.
```

Comment: so how would I use this in conjunction in specifying what string it should come from?  Like I need the data for settings=.

Comment: Access the key in the second example (`values.get("settings")`).  Or if it's a properties file, use `propertiesFile.getProperty("settings")`.

Comment: Ok so I would use the second example but 2 things. 1. when do I call the while function? and 2. when/how do you call the value.get function?

Comment: So the first - that's a loop, and you're basically reading in every value from the file. Second, I strongly encourage you to read the documentation for [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)), as that's something you kind of have to know.

Comment: Ok so run the while when needed but please can you just say when you would and how you would use the value.get?